# Given a 3 digit number by user, find and print it's minimum digit

Tags: c, if-statement, nested

I have tried a C program which takes a 3-digit integer from user, then find and print it's minimum digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Enter a 3-digit integer : ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a<b){
        if(a<c){
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",a);
        }
        else printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",c);
    }
    else {
        if (b<c){
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",b);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this is not the right way, as everytime i am being needed to press enter while giving the 3 digit input.

Comment: doing `scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);` you read 3 numbers, not 3 digits

Comment: Always better use `fgets()` for user input, but try `if (scanf("%1d%1d%1d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: @Maria: Using the result of `scanf` without checking the return value of the function is not safe. See the following link for more information: [A beginner's guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to read in 1 number instead of 3.

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

You can then divide the int by 100 to get the most significant digit because of how dividing integers works.

```
a = num/100;
```

To get the middle digit we need to get rid of the least significant digit first by dividing by 10 and then mod that by 10.

```
b = (num/10)%10;
```

For the least significant digit all you have to do is the number mod 10

```
c = num%10;
```

You can then compare these numbers to find the minimum.

Edit: The way you compare your numbers is flawed. There should be an else statement after the last if to account for all cases.

```
if(b<c){
    printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",b);
}
else{
    printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",c);
}
```

The below code should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,num;
    printf("Enter a 3-digit integer : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    a = num/100;
    b = (num/10)%10;
    c = num%10;
    if(a<b){
        if(a<c){
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",a);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",c);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(b<c){
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",b);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry but your solution does not work for all the 3 digit numbers

Comment: @bruno my number separation works, but the way the numbers are compared in the original post is flawed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @bruno can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: just think about the logic of your code, do not even look in details, just the structure must warn you

Comment: Code can fail to print anything 321.

Comment: yes, and what I was speaking about is the `if (b<=c){` without else, it is non logic to do that test without an else because all must be symetric

Comment: thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica for giving an example. I have updated my post again. I didn't trace through comparing the numbers because the post was mostly about separating the digits

Comment: @AndrewF if you was more curious you see I speak about 321 in my answer ^^ I preferred you found by yourself even with help, because we learn more by our self

Comment: @bruno well I understand the problem now. Thanks for pointing out that there was an error in my solution.

Comment: I am not understanding that what the problem was with previous code. I mean apart from  the comparison of the actual code, i'm not finding any problem with the previous seperation.

Answer (score 4):

you have two problems :

- doing `scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);` you read 3 numbers, not 3 digits.
- if the digits are for instance 321 then you print nothing because there is no `else` for the test `if(b<c)`

to read 3 digits you can do `scanf("%1d%1d%1d",&a,&b,&c);` but the read number can have its digits separated.

a way to do can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a,b,c;
    printf("Enter a 3-digit integer : ");
    if ((scanf("%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c) == 3) &&
        isdigit(a) &&
        isdigit(b) && 
        isdigit(c))
      printf("%d is the minimum digit\n",
             ((a < b) ? ((a < c) ? a : c)
                      : ((b < c) ? b : c))
             - '0');
    else
      puts("invalid values");

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall n.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a 3-digit integer : 123
1 is the minimum digit
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a 3-digit integer : 321
1 is the minimum digit
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a 3-digit integer : 213
1 is the minimum digit
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a 3-digit integer : 1ae
invalid values
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone <3

Comment: @Maria again, you accepted an answer which is wrong because it does not solve your second problem

Comment: `unsigned char a,b,c;  ... if ((scanf("%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c) == 3) && isdigit(a) && isdigit(b) && isdigit(c))` would simplify.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I do the cast because of a remark [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) made me several times, depending on the fact the compiler use signed or unsigned char the result without the cast can be false. This is why I added the cast to `unsigned char`

Comment: [My suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899468/given-a-3-digit-number-by-user-find-and-print-its-minimum-digit/62899622?noredirect=1#comment111232184_62899622) does not use `char` so "compiler use signed or unsigned char" does not apply.  It uses `unsigned char a,b,c;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes but how to  be sure "%c" is valid in `scanf` for an unsigned char if by default a char is signed ? Is the norm say it is ok ?

Comment: `%c` usues "the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the
initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence" .  As  a _character array_ (typically of size 1), code can use `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  `%c` does not specify a pointer to `char`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica oh thank you, I edit my code then

Comment: Using `"%c"` with `unsigned char *` or `signed char *` is uncommon, but legitimate.  I suppose it deserves an SO question - if one does not exist already.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, and I do not like to "force the hand" of the compiler/libs, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You'd better ask for one number, and do the following:

- If the number is larger than 999 or smaller than 100, the number is invalid.
- Try to get the first, the second and the third digit, you can do this as follows (imagine the number being the integer number `x`):

  ```
   x / 100 is the first digit (you divide by 100, and as both x and 100 are integers, 
                               the integer division (rounding down) is used)
   x mod 10 is the third digit (you take the whole number, modulo 10)
   (x / 10) mod 10 is the second number
  ```

Let's give an example for explaining the calculation of the second number (for `x` being 261):

```
x / 10 equals 261 / 10 = 26 (integer division)
(x / 10) mod 10 = 6 => which is indeed the second number of 261.
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3

int check(char *string, int i){
    if(string[i]<'0' || string[i]>'9'){
            printf("%s","invalid entry, not an integer");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char string[MAX+1];
    fgets(string, MAX+1, stdin);
    
    int min = string[0]-'0';
    if(check(string,0)==-1) return -1;
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        int j=string[i]-'0';
        if(check(string,i)==-1) return -1;
        if(j<=min) min=j;
    }
    printf("%d\n",min);
}
```

Input: 568 
Output: 5

Explanation: You provide a three character string.
The character 0 in ascii have a decimal value of 48. That means, the difference between the ascii digit's decimal value and the actual integer is 48. So to convert the character digit into integer, we have to subtract 48. The rest of the code is obvious.

This program does not check if all the characters are digits. But you can include a check yourself.

link to an ascii chart: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Comment: Thanks to everyone <3 I've got my answer.

Comment: "The character 0 in ascii have a decimal value of 48." except if the compiler does not follow ASCII ! you cannot suppose '0' is 48, just use '0' to not make assumption. You have an undefined behavior if the user does not enter a word of exactly 3 characters, and also if the user enter aze the result if 49 ...

Comment: @rsonx my thinking is an answer must also take into account the problems the OP did not see/speak about, this is part of the learning. And I did that remark to you in the same way, to help you

Comment: @rsonx I just see you edited your answer, an other hint  : look at *isdigit* whose check a char is a digit (you do not have to do it by yourself), and the similar functions *isalpha* etc

Comment: nice hint, now the program is probably free of undefined problems and compiler not using ascii problem as well.

Comment: @rsonx no, look better at *check* definition ^^

Comment: I see you found, I just edited your answer to remove a typo in the code, you can look at the edition historic. Happy S.O. and coding

Comment: @bruno Thanks a lot for helping. But your code is a little difficult for me to understand as i am just a beginner. Maybe when i will learn everything about C programming, then i will understand your code completely.

Comment: @Maria what you do not understand on my code ? Notice the answer you accepted is the worst, there are 4 times the same printf and there is no detection if the value entered is not a 3 digit number, that is sad (and it was false when you accepted it and we had to insist to allow the OP to correct it). Please use my answer to put new remarks to not 'pollute' the answer of rsonx ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider that your input will always a be string and don't bother converting from string to int (that's what scanf is doing).  Since a char is an int, you can just read one char at time and treat it as an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("Enter a 3-digit integer : ");

    int ans = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        c = fgetc(stdin);


        if(c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "'%c' is invalid", c);
            return 1;
        }

        if(c<ans){
            ans=c;
        }

    }
    printf("answer = %c", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~/user_home/eclipse-workspace-sri/trey
$ make
cc     blah.c   -o blah

Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~/user_home/eclipse-workspace-sri/trey
$ ./blah.exe
Enter a 3-digit integer : 391
answer = 1
Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~/user_home/eclipse-workspace-sri/trey
$ ./blah.exe
Enter a 3-digit integer : 5g9
'g' is invalid
Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~/user_home/eclipse-workspace-sri/trey
$ ./blah.exe
Enter a 3-digit integer : 596
answer = 5
```